# Does the end user need a license for embedded software? Or just the manufacturer?

Tags: united-states, copyright, software, licensing

According to [this answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/96784), legal responsibility for operations performed via computer isn't as simple as always attaching to the owner of the computer or to the person who hit the button. It attaches usually to the person who intended the thing being done to occur.

So if a toaster copies a copyrighted firmware file, is that legally being done by the person who plugged the toaster in and told it to toast, or by the manufacturer/firmware author who built a toaster that, when you press the "make toast" button, actually makes a copy of a copyrighted work?

Only one of these people would need a license to do the copying (the other is the copyright holder).

It seems like the person who built the product is actually legally doing the copying; I neither intend nor expect to copy things when I use my kitchen appliances. But then why do most appliances that include software come with lengthy license agreements? Am I free to decline those agreements and still toast my bread?

Comment: You are assuming the manufacture itself owns the copyright, or is properly licensed to copy and deploy the firmware?

Comment: Yes, I am assuming here that the manufacturer owns the firmware copyright as its author.

Answer (score 0):

You may technically build a device that downloads the illegal software from the Internet first time it starts, but this does not make that server legal so not helpful. Any legal enforcing would likely to go after your server first.

However the possibility to build the software right on the device may allow to integrate the code available under incompatible open source licenses and even some proprietary licenses, as long as the source code is still provided under any conditions. If the end user does not share the distribution, sharing and distribution chapters of the licenses do not apply, making much more licenses compatible.

This trick is sometimes used to compile proprietary device drivers into Linux kernel on the client machine: Linux kernel under GPL is the legally obtained source, the source code of the device driver is proprietary but made available anyway and can be built together with the kernel, user cannot distribute such a modified kernel under GPL without violating license agreements of GPL and proprietary code but does not need to - the modified kernel on only for running on the device where it has been built.

Users generally hate this approach because it often goes wrong and must be redone after every kernel update. In these days there is lots of open source software available under licenses permissive enough making it not worth effort and complexity involved.

Comment: I don't think I meant to ask the question you are answering. I am talking about a device with a typical technical comstruction: when you turn it on, it copies it's manufacturer supplied firmware from storage into main memory and starts executing it. I am asking about why or whether, if the manufacturer who holds the copyright made it do that, the user would need a license to the firmware to operate the device.

Comment: Absolute majority of computers copy programs from storage to RAM and only then execute, so no invention here. And these programs more often than not are still copyrighted.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the manufacturer provides the copyrighted work to the end user legitimately and with a license or implied license to copy. That is to copy by the inherent action of the device.

Comment: If the manufacturer supplied the user with an explicit license, with terms the user would rather not follow (say, no making toast on Sundays or the license is revoked), would the user actually need the license?